# How to batch files run together?

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

If I were to have multiple batch files run one after another in VB.NET, would they run at the same time or would they wait for the first ones to finish before moving on the next?

Comment: How do you plan to run the batch files?

Comment: Just going to have several line of `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat")` one after another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will run concurrently unless you go out of your way to prevent that from happening.  `Process.Start()` does not block once the process has been launched.  However, you can block by using `Process.WaitForExit()`.

For example, this will run 3 batch files at the same time:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat")
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat")
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat")
```

This will run them one at a time:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat").WaitForExit()
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat").WaitForExit()
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat").WaitForExit()
```

You have more control over when the blocking takes place by saving the process to a variable and calling `WaitForExit()` later in the code:

```
  Dim p1 = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("batch.bat")
  ' Do stuff that doesn't need to wait for process to finish
  p1.WaitForExit()
```

Answer (score 1):

They will run together. If you want it to wait, create a ProcessStartInfo object, add it to the Process.Start call, and assign the Start method's response to a process. Then call the process's WaitForExit method.